# Python, trying to count some items in a list then stop but loop gets stuck

Tags: python, list, loops, count

I got a program where you have a list and you have to count the number of words up to and including the word "sam".

```
import random

def sumWords(list):
    numWords = 0
    for i in list:
        if i != "sam":
            numWords += 1
    return numWords

wordList=["plant", "dog", "sam", "rose", "monkey", "happy", "coral"]    
print(sumWords(wordList))
```

But this counts ALL the words but Sam.

I tried doing a `while i != "sam":` instead of `if` but that puts it into an infinite loop.

Feel like I'm missing something simple here.  Keep in mind though, I'm still relatively new at Python.

Comment: It works for me. Note: do not use `list` as variable name as it is built-in type in Python

Comment: First figure out how you would do it by hand. Only once you've done that should you start to write code.

Comment: Add an `else: break` so that you don't keep going through the list after "sam" i.e. break the `for` loop. If you want it to include the count of "sam" you will also need `numWords += 1` before the `break`

Comment: Your loop goes all the way to end of the list.

Comment: So, you guys are saying the loop works for you when you put the while statement in?  Cause, again, I keep getting a "TimeLimitError: Program exceeded run time limit. on line 7" error.  

When I run it it'll go to the numWords += 1 line back to 
while i  != "sam" 
add 1 to numwords
go back to i != "sam" etc, etc.

Granted, I am running this in a web based Launchcode environment so that's messing it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `break` statement when `i =="sam"`. It will ensure you loop will only iterate until `sam`, rather than the whole list.

```
def sumWords(list):
    numWords = 0
    for i in list:
        numWords += 1 # Increment in each iteration.
        if i == "sam": # if condition matches, break from the loop
            break 
    return numWords
```

Usage:

```
print sumWords(wordList)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need a function for this. Find the index of the word and add 1 with it to include that word.

```
 wordList.index('sam') + 1
```

Comment: though your's one is a more *pythonic* answer, this is not so helpful for OP, as he struggled to understand, how loop works and all that. I think, the answer should be about what he has done wrong in his code.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I saw some answers was already there analyzing OP's function. Your answer is a good one. I showed a different way to do the same thing. Also I have commented in OP's post about why his code is not working.

Comment: Actually, I'm up for other ways of doing things AND an explanation on why my way wasn't (but could) work.  So, thanks to both camps!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop doesn't break, so you just keep counting the words until the end of the list. What you should do is break out of the loop when you reach something equal to `"sam"`, which you simply need to rewrite your code to this:

```
for i in list1:
    numwords += 1
    if i == "sam":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't stop counting at `sam` but skipping it. You should reverse the `if` clause and `break`.

```
def sumWords(my_list):
    numWords = 0
    for i in my_list:
        numWords += 1
        if i == "sam":
            break
    return numWords
```

And, you can simplify your function by:

```
def sumWords_simple(my_list):
    return my_list.index('sam')+1
```

`index` return the first index of the first `sam` in the list. Python is `zero-based` index. Without `+1`, it will be the sum up to but not including `sam`. With `+1`, it will include the fisrt `sam`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `for` loop, change the `if` statement

```
def sumWords(list):
    numWords = 0
    for i in list:
        numWords += 1
        if i=='sam':
            break
    return numWords
```